# Bot Service Migration - 'failed to find any Azure subscriptions for the current user.' error message

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have tried to migrate some bots from the Bot Framework Portal (dev.botframework.com) to the Azure Bot Service but I keep getting the 'failed to find any Azure subscription for the current user.' message.

To give some context on this:

- I have an account for each environment - DEV, STAGING and PROD - and for each one of these accounts, I have a set of bots created with the Bot Framework Portal.
- I use my personal company account, name.surname@company.com, to create bots in the Bot Framework Portal to test and debug them locally.
- I use that same company account to access the Azure portal and manage the Web Apps, Functions, CosmosDB, APP Insights, etc. that are used on these bots.
- On the Azure AD, I have two Directories but only in one of them I have an Azure subscription
- My Access Control (IAM) level for the Azure Resource Gorups is a 'Contriburor' role and not an 'Owner' role
- All bots have been developed using the Bot Builder Node.js SDK

I have tried the following:

- I logged in using my DEV account in the Bot Framework Portal and added my personal company account as an Admin/Owner in a couple of bots.
- Logged out and logged in using my personal company account
- Click the 'Migrate' button but still got the same message

So, why I'm still getting that error message? Is because the process is trying to find an Azure subscription in the Azure AD directory that doesn't have a valid one? Is it because I'm a 'Contributor' and not 'Owner'?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like it's something related to the company domain, the email account and the Azure AD. A colleague of mine that uses a '@outlook.com' account instead of the '@company.com' account was able to migrate them. 

As far as I could see, he has the 'Contributor' role and he said that he has the same two Azure AD and with only an Azure subscription in the same directory than me.

So not sure what could it be, but at least he can do it.

Comment: are you a Guest in the target directory, or are you an actual member of the target directory?

Comment: Thanks Eric for your reply. Yes, I'm a Guest in that target directory, but that's same as my colleague and he is able to do it..

Comment: Does your colleague have access to another directory also?

Comment: Both of us have access to the directory that has the valid subscription but he has another different directory that he did create and use some time ago and that he doesn't use anymore.

Could be that the directory with the valid subscription is his default one and it's not for me? Thanks

Comment: We've added a workaround to our troubleshooting docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-troubleshoot-general-problems#why-cant-i-migrate-my-bot

Comment: Thanks Eric! It seems that the migration process has improved and now it allows to select the Directory! 
By default, the directory that doesn't have a valid subscription is selected but I can change it to the other directory with a valid subscription! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With latest changes made on the `dev.botframework.com` portal, now you can select the target directory when migrating a bot to the Azure Bot Service.

For me, the target directory selected by default was the one that doesn't have a valid Azure subscription. But now I can select the other target directory, that has the valid subscription, and finish the migration process.